# Shell command to get remote system's ip address from its mac address?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have the HWAddress of remote machine but its IP address is not static and keeps changing. How do I get its IP address through shell?

Relevant questions mostly have the remote system in the same network, but in my case its not.

EDIT: I know its IP range.

Comment: The other system has to be link-local for this to be possible. MAC addresses are very intentionally not exposed to the Internet at large, for lookup in either direction.

Comment: ...if what you were asking for here were possible, folks wouldn't have needed to build [NoIP](https://www.noip.com/) or [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/home-users/) or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can get the ip from the mac address for a machine on a different network. The mac address of a particular interface is only used on the link layer, and you can't access the link layer frames between two nodes that aren't on your local network.

If you just need to get to a particular machine with a varying ip, then you might be able to get that done with a dynamic dns service. You pick a subdomain of one of the service's domains and they follow changes in the ip address so that the subdomain you picked always points to the same device as the initial ip address you gave them. [noip.com is one such provider.](http://freeddns.noip.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arp command, although this can be slow. To extract only the IP try the following;

arp -n | grep -i "MAC address here" | cut -d " " -f1

Comment: This only works if the system is on the same network. The OP explicitly specifies that the "remote" system is not.

Comment: Ah, I misread the post. Another possibility is if the OP has access to the DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Show the network interface names actives:

```
LIST_NET_IFACE=$(ip addr show | awk '/inet.*brd/{print $NF}')
echo "${LIST_NET_IFACE}"
```

2. Get the network interface used to the connection out. If it is the first in the above list, get with this command:

```
NET_IFACE=$(ip addr show | awk '/inet.*brd/{print $NF; exit}')
echo "${NET_IFACE}"
```

3. If necessary, get the network IP with its network mask:

```
NET_MASK=$(ip -o -4 addr list "${NET_IFACE}" | awk '{print $4}')
echo "${NET_MASK}"
```

4. If necessary, separate the IP:

```
NET_IP=$(echo ${NET_MASK} | cut -d/ -f1)
echo "${NET_IP}"
```

5. Finally, discovery and list the hardwares mac addresses at this network:

```
arp -n -i "${NET_IFACE}" | grep -v "incomplete"
```

6. To get a IP from a specifc hardware mac address stored in var REMOTE_MACADDRESS (with content in lower case):

```
REMOTE_IP=$( arp -n -i "${NET_IFACE}" | grep -v "incomplete" | grep "${REMOTE_MACADDRESS}" | awk '{print $1}' )
```